# Как программировать обои рабочего стола на windows 10/11?

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, canvas, рисование

Делаю много крутых анимаций из генеративного арта (в основном JS + Canvas), и много людей просят сделать такие обои.

Какие есть способы создавать программированые обои (желательно так же как в Canvas)? А то в гугле только платные проги с шаблонами.

Нужно чтобы можно было отправить один файл (к примеру .exe), и не заморачивать человека установкой дополнительных программ.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/856020/Draw-Behind-Desktop-Icons-in-Windows-plus

Comment: С тех пор как из Windows удалили Active Desktop и прочий интерактив, это возможно только с помощью сторонних программ или написанием своей, которая будет работать поверх рабочего стола и решать проблему скрытых под программой иконок.

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать пример того, что вам нужно отобразить как обои? Чтобы пробовать решить вашу задачу, нужно конкретно понимать, что именно должно получиться.

Comment: @aepot https://shumik.pp.ua/fxhash/flag/

Comment: @AlexKrass обидно(